# What clang function(s) can I use to find such declarations that has '&',such as 'int *m = &b'?

Tags: clang

I want to find declarations that has '&'; such as `int *m = &b`, then do something translations on such declarations.

Now, I use **ASTMatcher** `varDecl()` to find all **VarDecl**, and use `declVar->getType().getTypePtr().getAs<clang::PointerType>()` to get the pointer declartions.

What functions can I use to find such `'m = &b'` declarations next?

```
Matcher.addMatcher(varDecl(unless(parmVarDecl())).bind("varDecl"), &VarD);
virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
    ASTContext *Context = Result.Context;
    SourceManager &sourceManager_ = Context->getSourceManager();
    const VarDecl *declVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("varDecl");
    const clang::Type *type = declVar -> getType().getTypePtr();
    const clang::PointerType *pointer_type = type -> getAs 
    <clang::PointerType>();
    if(pointer_type != NULL){
        // what functions can I use to find m=&b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` is the unary operator inside of the variable declaration initialization. This makes the following matcher:

```cpp
varDecl(unless(parmVarDecl()), hasInitializer(unaryOperator(hasOperatorName("&"))))
```

**NOTE**: you can utilize a useful little tool by **clang** team: **clang-query**. It helps you to check your matchers interactively.

Have a happy hacking with clang!

Comment: Another question: I want to find all const variables. I use such ast matchers varDecl(hasType(isConstQualified())) to get all const variables. Now, I want to know the number of const variables and get the fisrt variable decleration in what matched. So in run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result){ }, what function can I use to get it?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful (can you, please, mark it as *accepted answer* then :) ?).
The other question looks more like an independent question. Short answer to it would be: `run` is a callback function that is called for each match individually. The order of the matches highly depends on the implementation and might vary from one version of Clang to another. Most likely you can expect that the first call will correspond to the first declaration, but you do need to check this.